# Shell Script to write to a file upto a certain point and then keep overwriting the file

Tags: shell, unix, command, overriding

I am trying to write a shell script , which will write the output of another script in a file and it will keep writing to that upto a certain point and then it will overwrite the file so that file size will remain within a well bounded range.

```
while true
do
    ./runscript.sh > test.txt
    sleep 1
done
```

I have tried to use infinite loop and sleep so that it will keep overwrite that file.

But, it shows a different behaviour. Till the point command is running , the filesize keeps on increasing. But, when i stop the command, the file size get reduce.

How can i keep overwriting the same file and maintain the file size along with it.

Comment: maybe you could share what runscript.sh does? It's out of my imagination.

Comment: It just keep generating continuous logs.

Comment: so runscript.sh itself is endless looping? It may be programmed to be like that? Why should it not?

Comment: Yes, But then, how can i imply a constraint on file size in such case. any suggestion ?

Comment: Your current script will overwrite the old test.txt in each loop.

Comment: What do you want to do when you have more lines and test.txt already has its maxsize? Remove the first 3 lines of test,txt and append the new ones at the end (difficult)? Or move test.txt to test.txt.1 and start a new log ? Or test once every loop?

Comment: You talk about overwriting; does that mean that when the file reaches the limit, you want to seek back to the start and write new data over the existing file?  If so, it is pretty straight-forward to implement in C and anything but simple to implement in shell.  Do you need the code to read/write lines, or can it wrap the data at arbitrary places in the data?  How will you know where the data is being written — that is, when inspecting the file, how will you know where the line breaks are? Or do you simply want the file truncated when it reaches a given size, so the new data goes at the start?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  I want it to keep removing the first few lines and append the new lines to the end.

Comment: You may think that's what you want, but you don't want that.  Suppose your file is N bytes long (say 1 MiB).  Suppose you want to add S new bytes (where S is perhaps 1 KiB).  The only way to do 'remove the first few lines and append the new lines at the end' is to copy N-S bytes from offset S to offset 0 in the file, and then add the S bytes at the end.  That is not a good idea.  You need to think of a different strategy.  You don't want the wrapping I suggested previously either — I never did think that was a good idea, but it was a possible interpretation of your desires.

Comment: The normal techniques for handling this sort of thing are using a new file when the current one grows too big and deleting old ones periodically, or copying the current file to a new file and then truncating the current file, or something along those general lines.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I can try with the option for generating the new file once the old one is full. But i seldom it will work for my project. How can make the script to generate the new file and write to it.

Comment: Is the `runscript.sh` running continuously, or are you running it repeatedly as shown in the question?  Does a single run grow the output file too big?  Your code truncates the output file each time `runscript.sh` is run.  How long does `runscript.sh` take to run? You may need to run it in the background, with `>> test.txt`, and then have another bit of script running in the background monitoring `test.txt`, copying it out to a new file when it gets big enough, then truncating the file. The append mode `>>` is crucial; it means that `runscript.sh` will write to the start of the truncated file.

Comment: Yes, runscript.sh is continous ,literally never ending and yes single run grows output file big. But when i interrupt the script, the file size is reduced is reduced. But, i want filesize to be reduced on runtime. Because this script will be running all day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112749/discussion-between-shubham-deodia-and-jonathan-leffler).

Answer (score 0):

I will do with below script

```
#!/bin/sh

Logfile=test.txt
minimumsize=100000 # define the size you want
actualsize=$(wc -c <"$Logfile")
if [[ $actualsize -ge $minimumsize ]]; then
    rm -rf "$Logfile"
    sh ./runscript.sh >> test.txt  
else
    #current_date_time="`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`"; #add this to runscript.sh to track when it was written
    #echo "********Added at :$current_date_time ********" #add this to runscript.sh to track when it was written
    sh ./runscript.sh >> test.txt
fi
```

Comment: I change the minimumsize=1000. But, it is still generating the file with size `23839 May 24 11:24 test.log` , Once i stop the script , file size reduce. How can i modify this to generate new file once the minimumsize is reached and delete the old one.

Comment: @shubhamdeodia I understand the problem, if single execution of runscript.sh causes the file size to go > 1000 then we are not removing the file. It will only check the next time of script execution

Comment: @shubhamdeodia Another approach I can think of is write a code to monitor the file size in runscript.sh recursively and if it reaches the limit then clean up the file and continue with your script.

Comment: But that would result into some amount of data loss. won't it ?

Comment: can you share the method with me.

Answer (score 0):

use `truncate -s <size> <file>` to shrink the file when its size is out of your boundary

Answer (score 0):

> I can try with the option for generating the new file once the old one
>   is full. … How can make the
>   script to generate the new file and write to it.

The following script, let's call it `chop.sh`, does that; you use it by feeding the output to it, specifying the desired file size and name as arguments, e. g. `./runscript.sh|chop.sh 999999 test.txt`.

```
File=${2?usage: $0 Size File}
Size=$1
while
    set -- `ls -l "$File" 2>/dev/null`  # 5th column is file size
    [ "$5" -lt "$Size" ] || mv "$File" "$File"-old
    read -r && echo "$REPLY" >>"$File"
do  :
done
```

The old (full) file would then be named `test.txt-old`.